# Firebase Analytics not working with web SDK installed on Expo app

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, expo, firebase-analytics

I have firebase realtime database up and running with my expo app. I'm using the web SDL with the following code in my index.js file.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

However no information is appearing in the analytics section of my firebase console dashboard. It says,

'Your Analytics data will appear here soon
We're ready to start collecting your Analytics data. Integrate the SDK, and within 24 hours you'll see your first reports.'

But have I not already integrated the SDK in my app with the code above? What am I missing here, is there some other link I need to make between the app and the dashboard?